# Python: Cannot join thread after redirected output to tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, join

I have a problem (Python just hang) if I enable the line "thread.join()" after redirected output to tkinter.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import threading

def run():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=test)
    thread.start()
    # thread.join()
    print('Want to add some code here')

def test():
    print('Process thread...')

class Redirect():
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self, text):
        self.widget.insert('end', text)

    #def flush(self):
    #    pass

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='TEST', command=run)
button.pack()

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(text)

root.mainloop()

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Current it prints out:

```
Want to add some code here
Process thread...
```

And what I expected (when using thread.join(after finished the thread):

```
Process thread...
Want to add some code here
```

If I don't use Redirect function, then the case work well, so I guess I need to add something into the class Redirect above.

Can you please help to take a look and give yur comment?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you join the thread, tkinter will be held up until the thread is finished, but you can't start the thread either because it won't give the desired output. The solution is to use a global variable to keep track of whether the thread has finished or not, then check it periodically with `root.after`.

```
def run():
    global completed
    thread = threading.Thread(target=test)
    thread.start()
    completed = False
    wait_for_finish()

def wait_for_finish():
    global completed
    if completed:
        print('Want to add some code here')
    else:
        root.after(100, wait_for_finish)

def test():
    global completed
    print('Process thread...')
    completed = True
```

This calls `wait_for_finish` every 100ms to check if `completed` is True. When it is, it runs the next part of the code.

Comment: Thanks Henry, it works like a charm. You save my night time.

Comment: No problem, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you.